# PCA: 7/8 variables important and approx. equal in first Principal Component

Tags: pca

I'm conducting a PCA and, according to my rotation table, 7/8 loadings are important (abs(loading)>0.3), and roughly equal in my first principal component. I'm not sure how to interpret this, as I think it doesn't represent a reduction in the number of variables (from 8 to 7), and they're all approx. equally correlated.

Also, the variance explained by PC1 seems quite low at 32%, and all 7 important variables in PC1 appear in PC2 and/or PC3.

Does this mean that PCA is not particularly meaningful in this case?

|  | PC1 | PC2 | PC3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Hep B titres | **0.31** | **-0.55** | 0.23 |
| Bilirubin | **0.43** | -0.05 | **-0.47** |
| Albumin | **0.33** | -0.02 | **0.39** |
| ALT | **0.38** | **0.41** | **0.30** |
| Fibrosis | **0.37** | 0.06 | **-0.58** |
| BMI | **0.37** | **0.51** | 0.25 |
| Family history | 0.17 | 0.18 | -0.25 |
| Age | **0.41** | **-0.48** | 0.13 |
| SD | 1.60 | 1.25 | 1.09 |
| % of var | 0.32 | 0.19 | 0.15 |
| Cum. % of var | 0.32 | 0.51 | 0.66 |

Comment: The first component is in effect close to the average of 7 variables, which suggests that a two-variable reduction, would be that average and the 8th variable. You may have good reason to be coy about A B C D E F G H, but interpretation of PCs is vastly aided by knowing what the variables represent.

Comment: Many thanks @NickCox.  I've edited my post to provide the variable names.  Your reply is helpful.  Please could I check that this means I should consider PC1 as Family History vs. 'the mean of the other variables' even though Family History is below the level I set to define importance?  (Also, I'm a big fan of your papers in the Stata Journal!)

Comment: Thanks for the further detail (and the fan mail). I see that averaging those 7 variables, even if they are standardized first, would make a composite that's hard to think about. I would check for some weird reason for your results: e.g. that a massive outlier is distorting the correlation structure.  As often, PCA sounds a wonderful technique in texts, but in practice it doesn't offer much help on the way towards an interesting or useful model. Which variable is your outcome or response?